# Spring Boot Update data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello Everyone i try to update my data using spring boot and react js
when i try to update the data , spring add the data in database ,  what i should to do this is my code

```
@PutMapping("/updateregion")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateRegion(@Valid @RequestBody Region region , BindingResult result)
{
    System.out.println("Update Region");
    Region region11 = rp.save(region);
     return new ResponseEntity<Region>(region11 , HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

this code save data but i need to update the data

Comment: You sure the ID of the record of region is not null, do not you?

Answer (score 0):

maybe yout problem is in your save method. Can you show me 
how do you differentiate insert new record to change ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the data then make sure that in the region object, your attribute associated with primary key should be there and not null.

For example in database, you have regions table which has integer type "id" as a primary key then "id" attribute in the "region" object should not be null and pointed towards the valid id in the database.

I hope you get my point.